# Postgresql Regular Espression to match and replcace only UPPERCASE word

Tags: regex, string, postgresql

I need to match and replace all UPPERCASE word in a Postgres string field like

```
'GARLASCO Cavour/Oriani'
'SANNAZZARO DE' BURGONDI Italia, 46 (Direzione Sud)'
'S.MARGHERITA STAFFORA Vallechiara (Bivio Montemartino)'
'GAMBOLO' Umberto I, 312'
```

I try with 
[A-Z\''.]{2,}

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('SANNAZZARO DE' BURGONDI Italia, 46 (Direzione Sud)',' \b[A-Z]{2,}\b','','g')
```

but it works only for string with 1 uppercase world like 'GARLASCO Cavour/Oriani'

Comment: `'SANNAZZARO DE' BURGONDI Italia, 46 (Direzione Sud)'` does not compile. Do you mean `'SANNAZZARO DE'' BURGONDI Italia, 46 (Direzione Sud)'`? Also, you know `\b` is not supported and you need to use `\y`? And what is the expected result?

Comment: Try `'^[A-Z[:space:].'']+\y'` pattern if the matches are  expected at the start of the string. `'g'` is redundant then.

Comment: Or, `'^.*?\y([[:upper:]][[:lower:]])'` and replace with `'\1'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry it's `'SANNAZZARO DE'' BURGONDI Italia, 46 (Direzione Sud)' ` and yes matches are expected at the start of the string and `'^[A-Z[:space:].'']+\y'`   works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(your_col_here,' '^[A-Z[:space:].'']+\y','')
```

This will replace the following matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z[:space:].']+` - 1+  uppercase letters (you may also replace `A-Z` with `[:upper:]`), whitespaces, dots or apostrophes at...
- `\y` - a word boundary.